# Custom 404 page not displaying

Tags: nginx

I just started with Nginx, and did the basic configuration, regarding configuring the PHP FPM, and I've changed the index file to be `index.php` instead of `index.html`. I also managed to get a handle on URL rewriting, although omitted from my example below for simplicity.

But in the default configuration file, there is a section dedicated to error pages, which looks as if it's ready to "plug and play". I have uncommented them, but they don't work correctly. I've gone through some 404-related questions on Stackoverflow, everyone seems to recommend that as the correct syntax.

Maybe the order of instructions is wrong, however, this **is** from the original sample configuration, so I don't know why it wouldn't be working.

I have remove all the commented lines from the configuration file, what's left is this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Now, when I go to `http://localhost/this-page-doesnt-exist`, the browser displays a literal `File not found.`, instead of the contents of my `/404.html` file.

Also, the permissions of my `404.html` file is the same as the permissions for the `index.php`, which is 644. The owner is the same as well.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try_files is passing your request for a none-existent file to index.php. This is in turn sends the request to php-fpm. By default Nginx returns the response from php-fpm to the client which is what you are seeing.

Update your php-fpm config to look like this and inform Nginx to handle error codes in the response.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The documentation is here: [fastcgi_intercept_errors](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors)